# Tomcat Kerberos Spnego authorization not working

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, kerberos, web.xml, spnego

I try to configure WebSSO for a Tomcat 7.0.69 with the build-in SPNEGO authenticator over Kerberos. When I access the application, a HTTP BasicAuth Dialog pops up and a debug entry is written in the catalina.out (see below).

My keytab file *sso.keytab* contains a principal who is registered on my AD-Server (via ktpass.exe & setspn.exe).

I switched on debug-mode for Kerberos, but I cannot find the problem. It simply stops at some point with *Entering logout*. Do you have any idea, in which step the authentication stops and what could be the reason for that? Any help is appreciated!

**catalina.out**

```
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /path/to/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/conf/sso.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Looking for keys for: HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Added key: 23version: 0
Looking for keys for: HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Added key: 23version: 0
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 17.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=server001.my.domain UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=171
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=server001.my.domain UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=171
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=189
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 11
     PA-ETYPE-INFO etype = 23, salt = 

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 19
     PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 2
     PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 15

>>> KdcAccessibility: remove server001.my.domain
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
     sTime is Thu Dec 15 15:35:42 CET 2016 1481812542000
     suSec is 830454
     error code is 25
     error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
     sname is krbtgt/MY.DOMAIN@MY.DOMAIN
     eData provided.
     msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 11
     PA-ETYPE-INFO etype = 23, salt = 

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 19
     PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 2
     PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 15

KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 17.
Looking for keys for: HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Added key: 23version: 0
Looking for keys for: HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Added key: 23version: 0
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 17.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=server001.my.domain UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=254
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=server001.my.domain UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=254
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=104
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=server001.my.domain TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=254
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=server001.my.domain TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=254
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1666 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1666
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove server001.my.domain
Looking for keys for: HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Added key: 23version: 0
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply HTTP/my.host.com
principal is HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Will use keytab
    [LoginContext]: login success
Commit Succeeded 

    [LoginContext]: commit success
Found KeyTab /path/to/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/conf/sso.keytab for HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Found KeyTab /path/to/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/conf/sso.keytab for HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Found ticket for HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN to go to krbtgt/MY.DOMAIN@MY.DOMAIN expiring on Fri Dec 16 01:35:42 CET 2016
Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = a0 82 13 79 30 82 13 75 a0 30 30 2e 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mech Token
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: received token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenInit
SpNegoContext: negotiated mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Looking for keys for: HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN
Added key: 23version: 0
        [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
        [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
    [LoginContext]: logout success
```

the *recieved token* is a lot longer, I shortened it

**krb5.ini**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MY.DOMAIN
    default_keytab_name = FILE:/path/to/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/conf/sso.keytab
    default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    permitted_enctypes   = rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96

[realms]
    MY.DOMAIN  = {
        kdc = server001.my.domain
        admin_server = server001.my.domain
        default_domain = MY.DOMAIN
}

[domain_realm]
    .my.domain = MY.DOMAIN
    my.domain = MY.DOMAIN
```

**jaas.conf**

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="/path/to/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/conf/sso.keytab"
    principal="HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN"
    debug=true;
};
```

**web.xml**

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>SSO Login</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**Architecture**

- AD Server Windows Server 2016
- Application-Server Unix-Redhat6 with Oracle JVM and Tomcat 7.0.69
- Client Windows 10 with Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Can we get more details on your architecture - what OS is Tomcat running on and is it running on a (hopefully) separate server from the Active Directory (AD) domain controller?  What OS version and web browser/version is your client running on/using?  Which AD version do you have?  I have a feeling what is causing the 'PREAUTH FAILED/REQ" message but I wanted to get these details from you first.

Comment: @T-Heron thank you for your response! I added the information to the description. I don't know the AD version. The  'PREAUTH FAILED/REQ" message appears also in my test environment where the authentication is working, so I figured that it may be irrelevant

Comment: The 'PREAUTH FAILED/REQ" message could be failing due to a couple of reasons.  One of which is the problematic server is not using the right keytab.  Can you validate it?  On that Tomcat server, within the same directory as the keytab itself, run this command, to see if you can pull a Kerberos ticket using the keytab:  _kinit -V -k -t /path/to/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/conf/sso.keytab HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN_

Comment: Result is _Authenticated to Kerberos v5_

Comment: The keytab is good then.  Next, please ensure that either the URL http://my.host.com or *.my.host.com is listed in the IE Local Intranet zone.  This ensures that the Windows credentials are passed from the client machine to the web server silently in the background during the authentication process.  Then clear the web browser cache, restart the browser and try again.  When the web server is not detected as a Local Intranet site, the credential dialog will pop up.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer- I was on holiday ;-) For IE Local Intranet zone there is a pattern defined, that matches the url (\*://\*.host.com). But still the credential dialog appears. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Next thing to check is, for a time issue.  On your Application Server (Unix-Redhat6 with Oracle JVM and Tomcat 7.0.69), make sure the system time is within 5 minutes of both the AD server and the Windows 10 client.  Is it?  If it is not, that is another reason you can see the credential dialog box pop up.  If the time on all 3 systems is within the Kerberos 5-minute clock skew, we will need to start examining at the application server logs.

Comment: Timestamp is synchronized on all computers, it looks correct for me

Comment: I re-read the error message, it appears the Kerberos client is trying to use RC4 encryption type against your Tomcat instance, and when Tomcat doesn't accept that, IE pops up the Basic Authentication dialog box.  Now that we've ruled out other potential problems, on the AD account with the SPN HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN, go to the Account tab.  Scroll down in the bottom section of that tab and make sure the box _This account accepts kerberos AES 128 bit encryption_ is selected.  The problem I think now is probably because the _AES 128_ box is not checked in the AD account properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [T-Heron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7057680/t-heron), I was able to find the solution. The keytab file was generated with the wrong encryption-type. For Windows7/10 and in my environment it had to be explicitly set to **AES256-SHA1**

The correct ktpass call:

```
ktpass -out D:\TEMP\sso.keytab -mapuser MYUSER -princ HTTP/my.host.com@MY.DOMAIN -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -kvno 0 -crypto AES256-SHA1 -pass ****
```

Thank you very much for the support!!!

Comment: Great to hear it!